# How do you ask people to give credit when they distribute your article?

Tags: sentence-construction

I wrote an article. At the end of my article, I want to say something like:

> Distribution of this article is welcomed, but please give credit to `www.mysite.com`.

But that looks like a very poor and broken English.

How do native English speakers usually say when they want to say something like that?

Comment: I don't think what you've written is "very poor and broken English" but if you really don't like it, consider something like *...please ensure the original source (www.mysite.com) is clearly identified.* That at least avoids the implications of ***give credit*** as ***show appreciation***, if all you're interested in is making sure any copies ***show attribution***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your acknowledgment. Your suggestion is more fluent and really like natural English. Is my first half (`Distribution of this article is welcomed`) looks like natural English?

Comment: Well, it's never really going to sound like "natural" English, because essentially you're writing "legalese". Which massively favours the rather stilted use of a passive construction, where in natural colloquial contexts we'd obviously be more likely to say ***You are** welcome to distribute this article [but...].* But it's entirely a stylistic choice on your part whether to use an "informal, chatty" style or to mimic the way lawyers write legally-binding contracts. Note that lawyers probably wouldn't mention ***welcome*** anyway (but they might say *you **may** reproduce this article*).

Comment: ...another alternative would be *but please **acknowledge** mysite.com*. But imho you were fine with your original phrasing, so I wouldn't fret too much about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of EIA.gov, a website publishing data available for re-use. They are saying the same thing you are looking for, but in a more "legalese" way as FumbleFingers mentioned:

> U.S. government publications are in the public domain and are not
>   subject to copyright protection. You may use and/or distribute any of
>   our data, files, databases, reports, graphs, charts, and other
>   information products that are on our website or that you receive
>   through our email distribution service. However, if you use or
>   reproduce any of our information products, you should use an
>   acknowledgment, which includes the publication date, such as: "Source:
>   U.S. Energy Information Administration (Oct 2008).

In your case I would say "Distribution or re-use of this article is welcomed. Please acknowledge the author and source, e.g. [Insert your article source here]"